# Getting files out of an NTFS-formatted system disk via USB

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, external-drive

I have replaced an old SATA disk in my laptop with an SSD. Now I want to get some files (that I thought I backed up but I didn't) from the old disk. I have an external disk enclosure that connects the old disk to the laptop via USB.

The computer can see the disk, and I have the option to convert it to "Simple volume" (losing all data stored there in the process). However, I cannot simply open it in Explorer and copy the files.

Is there perhaps some kind of utility or a method that can help extract files from the USB-connected NTFS drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally be able to do it using [Paragon Drive Copy 11](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/dc-professional/) free demo version.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a partition tool like http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Although NTFS file systems should be readable from a USB disk enclosure (I do this all the time). You might have a dynamic volume though and some OS versions don't support this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.You're right it's a Dynamic volume. The Partition Wizard you suggested offers option to convert to simple disk which would erase its contents.